# Pydev cannot import module that is available in Python IDLE

Tags: python, pydev, pyodbc

I tried to used pyodbc on a win10 computer and I use py 3.6. The module is installed with pip and I have no problem using this module in Python IDLE, however when I tried to use it in PyDev, it shows that the module cannot be resolved.
[Not resolved module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k3zV.png)

However it has no problem to run directly from the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/009Ym.png)

Does anyone has any clues? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the same virtualenv in both IDLE and PyDev?

Comment: Nevermind I used PyCharm and this software have no issue importing Pyodbc, and you can obtain a free student license and ionically it can set the layout as "eclipse"...

Comment: It's a good call, I think probably no, but the interpreter selected in Pydev is python 32 bit though, the pyodbc does not work in python 64.

Comment: You can configure PyDev to point to the 64 bit version, but honestly, I far prefer PyCharm!